# Simple GWT hosting

Tags: gwt, static, hosting

I have designed a website with the GWT, This is purely a static site and it doesnt have any servlet or any rpc part involved in it. Its just a plain static pages in GWT .I have compiled with the GWT and there are all related html ,.js files are present in the public folder. Now i want to host the same in any of the web host.

1. Good web host to host this web site.
2. Procedure to upload the GWT compiler output files into the web host.

Note:- I tried with the google app engine but it had issues as i have couple of video files that needs to be uploaded which is embedded in the webpage.

Thank you

Comment: I asked a similar-ish question over on superuser (not GWT specific though) http://superuser.com/questions/8600

Answer (score 4):

I think this is not really a "GWT hosting" problem, but rather a "hosting" problem. Finding a good host is not that problematic though. I suggest you to look up webhosting in your own language and country, which makes it easier to contact the hosting company in case of problems.

I don't suggest a free hosting, unless you really can't afford a payed host. Your site being static, would require a cheap host. Free hosts have always got some problems and some advertising attached to your content in some way (frames and popups).

For the uploading part, you usually get a (s)ftp account which you can use to upload your files to the server with a (s)ftp client. Good companies provide detailed description of this process for their server, and as being a paying customer, you will usually get technical support as well.

It's good to know that a host alone doesn't include a domain. To have a yourcompany.com address, you need to register it, and you will have to pay a (low) registration fee. Some compaines offer the domain as part of the hosting service.

Answer (score 2):

I host a few small GWT (client-only) apps on the same site I host my blog.  There's no problem.  In the end GWT is just javascript with a couple of html files, and thats all thats really being hosted.

Answer (score 2):

Ummmmm...why not host it on [Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/tutorials/1.6/appengine.html)?

It's free and deployment is easy if you're using Eclipse.